# Get HTML color code for dark table Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatable, colors

I have a dark themed Bootstrap table and I need to color using in (odd) and (even).

Does anyone know the HTML color code using in Bootstrap table **table table-striped table-dark**?

I really need the (odd) and the (even).

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome or Firefox, you can "inspect" any part of your HTML table (or the example page of Bootstrap at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#striped-rows - second table).

Just right click (Mac: control+click) on the colored table row background and choose "inspect". In the top right part of the opening window you should see a list of the class names and color codes. I see a "background-color: #212529" for the table and an additional "tr:nth-of-type(odd)" with 5% opaque (95% transparent) white: "background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.05)"

I measured the resulting "brighter" color and got #2B3034.

Have Fun! :)